# Possible to use ReadAllText with listBox.SelectedItem?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listBox in Winforms, that show text files from a folder on my computer. When I select a file/item in the listBox i want to be able to see the content of the text file in a textBox.

**This is the code that shows the directory in my listBox:**

```cs
  private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\testing");
      FileInfo[] files = dInfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
      foreach (FileInfo file in files)
      {
          listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
      }
  }
```

**And then I try to show the content of the selected text file:**

```cs
  private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
      string content = File.ReadAllText(curItem);
      textBox1.Text = content;
  }
```

Obviously the last part doesn't work, because I assume it wants the path to the selected file. But how can I give it the full path, if I don't know in advance what file will be selected on the listBox?

The exception that I get is this (I guess it's no surprise):

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The file 'C:\Users\OldMan\source\repos\WindowsFormsTests\testing\bin\Debug\LICENSE.txt' was not found.'

Comment: Look at `System.IO.Path.Combine`.  That will allow you to combine the folder name you are using ("c:\testing" in your code) with the file name the user has picked out.  Your code is just trying to read the file name, so the system looks in the current directory (which is where your program was run from - unless someone changes it).  So it's looking in [stuff]\bin\Debug (where your program is located) and not where you really want it.

Comment: @Flydog57 great simple answer. Something I could immediately understand and use. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to add the array of `FileInfo` objects as a `DataSource` to the list box, and set the `"Name"` property as the `DisplayMember` and the full path (`"FullName"`) as the `ValueMember` property:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set the datasource property of the list box to the FileInfo array
    listBox1.DataSource = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\testing").GetFiles("*.txt");

    // Set the display property as the file name and the value property as the file path
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    listBox1.ValueMember = "FullName";
}
```

Now, the listbox will show the file names, but we can access the associated path using the `SelectedValue` property (which returns the `FullName` for the selected item):

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thx Rufus. This works for me too, but I need to read up on some of the words to understand it better. Are there any advantages of using this method compared to the "simple" solution of Flydog57 ?

Comment: I don't know if the other method is simpler or not, but this introduces you to databinding and the concept of having items that have both a display property and a value property. But you could use your code as-is if you modify it to: `File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(@"c:\testing", curItem));`

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ListBox_57860008
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BindingList<FileInfo> lstbx_DataSource = new BindingList<FileInfo>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox1.DataSource = lstbx_DataSource;
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
            listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
            fillDataSource();
        }

        private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(((FileInfo)listBox1.SelectedItem).FullName);
        }

        private void fillDataSource()
        {
            foreach (string item in Directory.GetFileSystemEntries("c:\\temp\\", "*.txt"))
            {
                lstbx_DataSource.Add(new FileInfo(item));
            }
        }
    }
}
```